# Apache Atlas wont start with separate ensemble of Zookeeper

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper, apache-atlas

I am setting up Apache Atlas, with an existing ensemble of Zookeeper, but using local HBase / Solr. However, HBase still tries to kick off its own ZK ensemble rather than use the existing one.

I am trying to get **Apache Atlas** running with a separate ensemble of ZooKeeper. However, HBase wont recognise the existing ZK ensemble and still tries to start up it's own ensemble.

I have already set the LOCAL environment settings:

> ```
> -bash-4.2$ env | grep LOCAL
>
> MANAGE_LOCAL_HBASE=true
> MANAGE_LOCAL_SOLR=true
> ```

and

```
HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false
```

And configured the HBase as follows in **hbase-site.xml**:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
 <property>
    <name>hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
 <property>
    <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
    <value>/hbase</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I can see that ZK is up and running by checking zkCli.sh, and no HBase Nodes exist:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 0] ls /
[cluster, configs, brokers, zookeeper, overseer, security.json, admin, isr_change_notification, autoscaling.json, controller_epoch, aliases.json, live_nodes, collections, overseer_elect, clusterstate.json, consumers, autoscaling, config]
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 1]
```

However, I am still getting the following error:

```
2019-06-06 11:06:59,045 WARN  - [main:] ~ Retrieve cluster id failed (ConnectionImplementation:551)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/hbaseid
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
```

HDFS is up and running too:

```
-bash-4.2$ jps
3537 SecondaryNameNode
7722 Jps
6716 ZooKeeperMain
3342 NameNode
3039 QuorumPeerMain
```

Any ideas anyone?

Cheers!

Comment: I have the same problem now.